# Accidentally deleted steam download files

Tags: steam

I am currently downloading a game on Steam. I accidentally deleted some files in the downloading folder under `steamapps` but the download ran normally. Would the missing downloading folder files have any effect on the outcome of the game once it has finished downloading? If so, what could happen?

Comment: How did you even delete this accidentally lol. Anyways, steam should normally check the game before launching it so it would download the missing files.

Answer (score 6):

It depends on the game, but essentially anything can happen - the game might run normally, the game might not launch at all, or the game might crash unexpectedly. It's not really worth finding out, so your best bet is to have Steam verify that all the game's files are present and accounted for.

What you should do is right-click on the game in your Steam library, then go Properties -> Local Files -> Verify Integrity of Game Cache.

This will make Steam double check that all of the files it expects to be present are there, and it'll download stuff if anything is missing. Once it's done, the game is **definitely** ok to play.